# canonical libpthread distribution

Tags: c, pthreads

Is [NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) from [glic](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl;h=5e434caab39fede6ffcf1be7fbc6611e6fd5492b;hb=HEAD) source tree the canonical [libpthread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) distribution for [pthread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)?

Want to make sure because there's also an ambiguous *libpthread* named project hosted on [Hurd](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/hurd/libpthread.git/tree/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "canonical libpthread" -- it is different on different platforms.

On Linux, GLIBC provides POSIX thread implementation as part of it (in the `nptl` directory), and that's what most Linux programs use. But it's possible to use other C libraries (uClibc, dietlibc, Musl), and they provide *their own* thread implementation. It would generally *not* work to try to link NPTL with Musl (or any other non-GLIBC libc implementation).

On Solaris, or AIX, or HP-UX, the POSIX thread implementation is completely different and has *nothing* to do with NPTL (or any other open-source implementation).

> there's also an ambiguous libpthread named project hosted on Hurd.

That looks like a fork of GLIBC with Hurd-specific patches.